# Assistance with refining saving output from Python script to text file

Tags: python, text, text-files, pypdf

I need a little help figuring out why this isn't working as expected.
the following code, opens a PDF file, extracts the text and should save the individual text files according to the name of the PDF file, however its not producing any output. please help. code is as follows:

```
import PyPDF2
import os
import glob


directory = 'C:/LIVE/2017/'

fileStructure = glob.glob("C:/LIVE/2017/*")
names = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob('C:/LIVE/2017/*')]

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    with open(os.path.join(directory,file), 'rb') as pdfFileObj:
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj, strict=False)
        pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
        number_of_pages = pdfReader.getNumPages()

        for page_number in range(number_of_pages):
            page = pdfReader.getPage(page_number)
            page_content = page.extractText().encode('utf-8')
            getFileName = os.path.basename(pdfFileObj.name)
            bcn = getFileName.rsplit(' ', 1)[-1]
            bcNum = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(bcn))[0]
            text_file = open(bcNum, "w")
            text_file.write(page_content)
            text_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it extract strings from the PDF to begin with? I've tried using PyPDF2 before and noticed it often has trouble getting text from PDFs if they're not formatted exactly right. I've had much more success using the module Tika.

```
from tika import parser

def read_pdf(pdf):
    raw = parser.from_file(pdf)
    return raw['content']

text_list = list()
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    raw_content = read_pdf(pdf)
    text_list.append(raw_content)
```

Comment: thanks will give it a try. PyPDF2 has worked relatively will for me.